# Show variable on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, average

Just and average calculator. Well, you can interact with the program putting
grades and selecting the mean. First, I couldn't make it work taking up the
mean, so I change it. Then, it gave an error every time I tried to select a
method, so nope. Then, the method wouldn't work correctly. So I finally got it
to work, except for one thing... it can't show me average.

```
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JLabel mostrar;
private double combo, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, sem1, sem2, fin, aux1, aux2;
private JRadioButton DosSemestres, CuatroParciales, TresParciales, DosParciales;
private JLabel SelecMetod, LBLMax , LBLMin, lblNota1, lblNota2, lblNota3, lblNota4, lblSem1, lblsem2, lblfinal;
private JButton NotaBoton, Calcular, Elegir;
private JLabel AreaSem1, AreaSem2, AreaPromedioFin;
private JLabel Clasi;


public Panel() {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(850, 556);
    //metodo de creacion de año electivo
    SelecMetod = new JLabel("Seleccione el metodo electivo: ");
    DosSemestres = new JRadioButton("1. Dos semestres de dos parciales cada uno");
    CuatroParciales = new JRadioButton("2. Cuatro parciales repartidos en un año electivo");
    TresParciales = new JRadioButton("3. Tres parciales repartidos en un año electivo");
    DosParciales = new JRadioButton("4. Dos parciales repartidos en un año electivo");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    Dimension size1 = DosSemestres.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension size2 = CuatroParciales.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension size3 = TresParciales.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension size4 = DosParciales.getPreferredSize();
    SelecMetod.setBounds(20, 5, size1.width, 20);
    SelecMetod.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    DosSemestres.setBounds(20, 25, size1.width, 20);
    CuatroParciales.setBounds(20, 55, size2.width, 20);
    TresParciales.setBounds(20, 85, size3.width, 20);
    DosParciales.setBounds(20, 115, size4.width, 20);
    group.add(DosSemestres);
    group.add(CuatroParciales);
    group.add(TresParciales);
    group.add(DosParciales);
    add(SelecMetod);
    add(DosSemestres);
    add(CuatroParciales);
    add(TresParciales);
    add(DosParciales);
    DosSemestres.addActionListener(this);
    CuatroParciales.addActionListener(this);
    TresParciales.addActionListener(this);
    DosParciales.addActionListener(this);

    //Notas minimas y maximas
    LBLMax = new JLabel("Ingrese la nota minima de excelencia academia: ");
    LBLMax.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    LBLMin = new JLabel("Ingrese la nota minima para aprobar: ");
    LBLMin.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    Dimension Not1 = LBLMax.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension Not2 = LBLMin.getPreferredSize();
    LBLMax.setBounds(440, 25, Not1.width, 20);
    LBLMin.setBounds(440, 90 , Not2.width, 20);
    add(LBLMax);
    add(LBLMin);

    textField = new JTextField("");
    textField.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    textField.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textField_2 = new JTextField("");
    textField_2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    textField_2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textField.setBounds(440, 55 , 60, 20);
    textField_2.setBounds(440, 120 , 60, 20);
    add(textField);
    add(textField_2);
    mostrar = new JLabel("La nota media es:" );
    mostrar.setBounds(440, 140, 180, 30);
    add(mostrar);

    Elegir = new JButton("Aceptar");
    Elegir.setBounds(440, 170, 120, 30);
    add(Elegir);
    Elegir.addActionListener(this);

    //Notas reales
    lblNota1 = new JLabel("Ingrese la primera nota:");
    lblNota2 = new JLabel("Ingrese la segunda nota:");
    lblNota3 = new JLabel("Ingrese la tercera nota:");
    lblNota4 = new JLabel("Ingrese la cuarta nota:");
    Dimension nota1 = lblNota1.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension nota2 = lblNota2.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension nota3 = lblNota4.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension nota4 = lblNota4.getPreferredSize();
    lblNota1.setBounds(30, 220, nota1.width, nota1.height);
    lblNota2.setBounds(30, 250, nota2.width, nota2.height);
    lblNota3.setBounds(30, 280, 280, nota3.height);
    lblNota4.setBounds(30, 310, nota4.width, nota4.height);
    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textField_1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textField_1.setBounds(250, 220, 40, 20);
    add(textField_1);
    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textField_3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textField_3.setBounds(250, 250, 40, 20);
    add(textField_3);
    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textField_4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textField_4.setBounds(250, 280, 40, 20);
    add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setVisible(false);

    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textField_5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    textField_5.setBounds(250, 310, 40, 20);
    add(textField_5);
    textField_5.setVisible(false);

    add(lblNota1);
    add(lblNota2);
    add(lblNota3);
    add(lblNota4);
    lblNota3.setVisible(false);
    lblNota4.setVisible(false);


    //Boton que calculara
    Calcular = new JButton("Calcular");
    Calcular.setBounds(130, 350 , 160, 40);
    add(Calcular);
    Calcular.addActionListener(this);

    //Promedios
    lblSem1 = new JLabel("El promedio del primer semestre es: ");
    lblsem2 = new JLabel("El promedio del segundo semestre es: ");
    lblSem1.setBounds(440, 220, 240, 40);
    add(lblSem1);
    lblSem1.setVisible(false);
    lblsem2.setBounds(440, 260, 250, 40);
    add(lblsem2);
    lblsem2.setVisible(false);
    AreaSem1 = new JLabel();
    AreaSem2 = new JLabel();
    AreaSem1.setBounds(520, 220, 80, 50);
    AreaSem1.setVisible(false);
    add(AreaSem1);
    AreaSem2.setBounds(520, 260, 80, 50);
    AreaSem2.setVisible(false);
    add(AreaSem2);

    lblfinal = new JLabel("El promedio final es: ");
    lblfinal.setBounds(440, 300, 240, 40);
    add(lblfinal);
    AreaPromedioFin = new JLabel();
    AreaPromedioFin.setBounds(520, 300, 90, 40);
    add(AreaPromedioFin);
    Clasi = new JLabel();
    Clasi.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    Clasi.setBounds(520, 350, 250, 50);
    AreaPromedioFin.setBounds(520, 360, 180, 40);
    add(Clasi);

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getSource() == Elegir){
            double min = (Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()));
            double aprobado = (Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText()));
            double R = ((min + aprobado)/2);
            mostrar.setText("La nota media es:  "+String.valueOf(R));}

    if(e.getSource() == DosSemestres){
        lblNota3.setVisible(true);
        lblNota4.setVisible(true);
        textField_5.setVisible(true);
        textField_4.setVisible(true);
        lblSem1.setVisible(true);
        lblsem2.setVisible(true);
        AreaSem1.setVisible(true);
        AreaSem2.setVisible(true);



        double nota1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()));
        double nota2 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()));
        double sem1 = (nota1+nota2)/2;
        double nota3 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_4.getText()));
        double nota4 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_5.getText()));
        double sem2 = (nota3+nota4)/2;
        double fin = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;    
        if(e.getSource() == Calcular){
              AreaSem1.setText(String.valueOf(sem1));
              AreaSem2.setText(String.valueOf(sem2));
              AreaPromedioFin.setText(String.valueOf(fin));
        }


    else if(e.getSource() == CuatroParciales){
        lblNota3.setVisible(true);
        lblNota4.setVisible(true);
        textField_5.setVisible(true);
        textField_4.setVisible(true);
        lblSem1.setVisible(false);
        lblsem2.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem1.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem2.setVisible(false);

        double nota1_1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()));
        double nota2_1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()));
        double nota3_1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_4.getText()));
        double nota4_1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_5.getText()));
        double fin_1 = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;    
        if(e.getSource() == Calcular){
              AreaPromedioFin.setText(String.valueOf(fin));}



                }
    else if(e.getSource() == TresParciales){
        lblNota3.setVisible(true);
        lblNota4.setVisible(false);
        textField_5.setVisible(false);
        textField_4.setVisible(true);
        lblSem1.setVisible(false);
        lblsem2.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem1.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem2.setVisible(false);

        double nota1_2 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()));
        double nota2_2 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()));
        double nota3_2 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_4.getText()));
        double fin_2 = (nota1+nota2+nota3)/3;    
        if(e.getSource() == Calcular){
              AreaPromedioFin.setText(String.valueOf(fin));}
                }


    else if(e.getSource() == DosParciales){
        lblNota3.setVisible(false);
        lblNota4.setVisible(false);
        textField_5.setVisible(false);
        textField_4.setVisible(false);
        lblSem1.setVisible(false);
        lblsem2.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem1.setVisible(false);
        AreaSem2.setVisible(false);

        double nota1_3 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()));
        double nota2_3 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()));

        double fin_3 = (nota1+nota2)/2;    
        if(e.getSource() == Calcular){
              AreaPromedioFin.setText(String.valueOf(fin));}

    }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tag this as "java" and "swing".

Comment: What are you asking us to do? When you ask a question on SO, please only post the code causing the trouble, and be clear about what you want to be fixed.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. You should NOT be using setBounds(). Instead you should be using [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double nota1 = (Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()));` is causing a potential `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the field is empty.  You should be using `textField_1.getText().isEmpty()` to check if the field has any text at all.  You should also be trapping the `NumberFormatException` in case the user inputs an invalid value.

A `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` will help reduce some of theses issues.  Have a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details.

When the user selects `1. Dos semestres de dos parciales cada uno`, you show new fields, but you try and process those fields before the user has entered anything into them which is further causing `NumberFormatException`

The following...

```
if (e.getSource() == DosSemestres) {
    //...
    if (e.getSource() == Calcular) {
```

Will never work.  The event can only have a single source, so it will either be `DosSemestres` OR `Calcular`, but never both.  This seems to be a significant source of your problem, along with the previous comments.

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

You might also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others